# Removed text with regex leaves whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How to remove text and whitespace?

For example:

```
http://www.exampleweb.com/myprogram.rar
http://www.examplebackup.com/mybackups.rar
http://www.exampleweb.com/myprogram1.rar
```

I use something likes this to get rid of second line:

```
http://www.examplebackup.com/.+?.rar
```

End result is:

```
http://www.exampleweb.com/myprogram.rar

http://www.exampleweb.com/myprogram1.rar
```

But I want something like that with no whitespaces left:

```
http://www.exampleweb.com/myprogram.rar
http://www.exampleweb.com/myprogram1.rar
```

Please help I'm total noob in regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you regex doesn't match the newline at the end, so it won't affect it. To fix this, add `\n` to the end.

[Regex101 demo of the idea](https://regex101.com/r/yV8tG2/1) -- notice, on the right, how the match isn't `movie`, it's `movie` with a newline after it.

A few other things that may or may not apply to your actual regex that I'd like to recommend:

- You need to escape your slashes (`/` => `\/`) in your regex, or it might cause issues.
- You need to escape literal full stops (`.` => `\.`) or it'll match any character in that position (i.e. `backup.rar` will match `backup:rar` as well)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be forgetting to escape your "any char" operator. Try this:

```
http://www.examplebackup.com/mybackups/.+?\.rar
```